# Mousedown event for frame control does not always fire

Tags: excel, vba, frame, mousedown

Hoping someone can help with this - I am trying to develop a class for userform textbox validation using events. I would like to prevent the user from exiting the textbox if the textbox text is not valid (such as blank or non-numeric value, etc.) for whatever reason. This would normally be done in the textbox exit event (using the Cancel argument), but the lack of the exit event for a class that contains a textbox defined WithEvents is well documented, so I am trying to take a different approach.

Instead of preventing the focus from leaving the offending textbox, I am trying to detect movement of the focus to a new control and then setting the focus back to the textbox. I am making progress, but have encountered a problem with controls located inside a frame control.
If the user clicks on directly on a control inside a frame, the mouse events for the control indicate that the focus has moved to the new control. But if the user clicks inside the frame (but not directly on a control in the frame), the focus moves to the first control in the frame, but there will be no event indicating this. So I tried using the frame's mousedown event so that the focus can be set back to the offending textbox.

This works well if I click in an area that is clearly inside the frame control. However, if I click just inside the frame border or on the frame caption area, the MouseDown event does not occur. I found MouseUp and Click events had the same problem. The result is that the focus has moved to a new control inside the frame, but this has not been detected.

But then I discovered that using the frame's Enter event produced the desired result - no matter where I click on the frame control, the Enter event occurs if the focus has moved. This is fine, except that the frame's Enter event code must be done at design time, since the enter event is also not available for a frame declared WithEvents in a class. This is annoying and I would like to be able to use MouseDown instead, but cannot solve this problem. I get the same result in Excel 2003, 2010, and 2013. Does anyone have any idea why the MouseDown and MouseUp events are sometimes missing as I described?